# PGFPlots: can a forced line break be added in the title command?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a some data plotted with `pgfplots`.  I would like to make the title two lines.  Can this be done?  I tried adding `\\` in the title command but that did nothing.  Additionally, I couldn't find anything in the manual.

In my `axis` command, I have the option `title = {text \\ text}` where I want to split the title.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title = {text \\ text}]
\addplot[smooth, samples = 100, domain = 0:2] (\x, 2);
\end{axis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Along with describing the problem, It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill I didn't really think this question needed a MWE.

Comment: Adding a MWE makes the question much clearer and eliminates the need for the person trying to help you to have to set it up and check that what they are proposing actually will work for you. I think perhaps egerg and DavidCarlisle can give you an answer without a MWE, but I don't think most others can.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `align=center` does the trick:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[align =center, title = {text \\ text}]
\addplot[smooth, samples = 100, domain = 0:2] (\x, 2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `compat = 1.10`?

Comment: @dustin Use `\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10,
            title/.append style={align =center}
            }`

Comment: @dustin: It should work. I don't have the latest version but so I cant test it but I am pretty sure it'll work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: It works on `1.10`.  I thought maybe it wouldn't since it was commented out.

Comment: Better use `title style = {align=left}` to just affect the title.

Comment: Hi Peter, I added an additional answer with a bit more information. I hope this is ok. Happy Halloween!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Yeah, that is a good idea to localize the `align=center'.

Answer (score 1):

- Add `title style = {align = center},` (`center`, `left`, or `right`) to the `axis` options. Then you can use `\\` to add line breaks. Basically, the **`align` option has to be given** in some form, see also at the end of this post.
- Peter's answer proposes `align =center` which will affect all text in the plot and this is maybe an unintended side effect.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    title style = {align = center}, 
    title = {\textbf{Title First Line}\\ Title Second Line},
    ]
\addplot[
    smooth, 
    samples = 20, 
    domain = 0:10,
    blue,
    mark = *,
    ] {x^2 - x +4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to know more about this, then have a look at the [`pgf` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), Chapter 17.4.3 (as of the time of writing).

[image]