# Modifying some features in a scatter plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to have the following modifications to the scatter plot.

The title should be typeset on two lines.

I would like a break on each axis indicating a skip from 0.  (When I was in junior high school, we used two 'parallel" wavy lines.)

`0` should be put in the lower left corner of the plot.

Remove the comma in the years.

I also have some question.  Why is the plot drawn in blue?  What is the diameter of each dot? How would I make the line connecting the dots to be dashed and drawn in a different shade of blue?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[grid=major, title=\textbf{Population of Pittsford in \boldmath$19^{\mathrm{th}}$ Century\unboldmath},
    ylabel = Population (in thousands),
    xlabel = Year,
    xmax=1900]

\addplot plot coordinates{(1800,1.1) (1810,1) (1820,0.9) (1830,1.2) (1840,1.5) (1850,1.5) (1860,1.5) (1870,1.7) (1880,1.75) (1890,1.75) (1900,1.9)};
\coordinate (Bottom Left) at (axis cs:1800,0);
\coordinate (Bottom Right) at ($(Bottom Left) + (axis direction cs:100,0)$);
\draw (Bottom Left) -- (Bottom Right);
\coordinate (Top Left) at ($(Bottom Left) + (axis direction cs:0,0.1)$);
\coordinate (Top Right) at ($(Top Left) + (axis direction cs:20,0)$);
\draw[red,thick] (Top Left) -- (Top Right);

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Multiline title: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176833/pgfplots-can-a-forced-line-break-be-added-in-the-title-command No comma's in the years: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31276/number-format-in-pgfplots-axis Dinscontinuities: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149081/collapse-range-in-x-axis-with-pgfplots-break-x-axis

Comment: @Maarten Dhondt  Do you know how to make the edits that I listed in the bounty?  (I included the edited code, and `tex.stackexchange` made a mess of it.)  Read the first six lines in the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, I think you should go with percusse's solution. But as per your explicit request, here you go:

1. I have no clue how to redefine the `axis x discontinuity` and `axis y discontinuity` to use smaller lines or to use them only left and bottom (instead of right and top too). So that's why I don't use them at all.
2. You don't need tick marks as you already have the `grid=major`. So I added `ytick style = {draw=none}, xtick style = {draw=none}` to get rid of them.
3. As to the rotations of your labels: you don't need a `tick label style = {}` inside another `tick label style = {}`. Just go for `yticklabel style = {font=\tiny, fill=white, rotate=0}, xticklabel style = {font=\tiny, fill=white, rotate=-45}`
4. So now for the discontinuities: I put them on top of your plot as
   `extra ticks` That's certainly a bad way to do it, but it makes it
   look the way you want it to look. Also it involves a lot of trial
   and error to find the "right" values for `xshift` and `yshift`:

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\def\discon{$\wr\!\!\!\wr$}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[   grid                = major,
                        /pgf/number format/1000 sep = {},
                        title               = Population of Pittsford in \\ 19\textsuperscript{th} Century,
                        title style         = {align=center,font=\bfseries},
                        ylabel              = Population (in thousands),
                        xlabel              = Year,
                        xmin                = 1790,
                        xmax                = 1900,
                        xtick               = {1800,1810,...,1900},
                        ytick style         = {draw=none},
                        xtick style         = {draw=none},
                        yticklabel style    = {font=\tiny, fill=white},
                        xticklabel style    = {font=\tiny, fill=white, rotate=-45},
                        ymin                = 0.6,
                        ymax                = 2, 
                        ytick               = {0.8, 1, ..., 2},
                        extra x ticks       = {1792},
                        extra x tick style  = {grid=none, xticklabel style={yshift=1.3mm, rotate=45, inner sep=.5pt}},
                        extra x tick labels = {\discon},
                        extra y ticks       = {0.7},
                        extra y tick style  = {grid=none, yticklabel style={xshift=1.1mm, rotate=90, inner sep=.5pt}},
                        extra y tick labels = {\discon}]
            \addplot plot coordinates{(1800,1.1) (1810,1) (1820,0.9) (1830,1.2) (1840,1.5) (1850,1.5) (1860,1.5) (1870,1.7) (1880,1.75) (1890,1.75) (1900,1.9)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** answers to comments:

1. `\def\discon{$\wr\!\!\!\wr$}`: This defines a new command `\discon` which I use as the symbol for discontinuities. It is build by using two `\wr` (in mathmode). The `\!` (negative thin space (normally −1/6 of a quad)) takes care of the spacing between those two `\wr`.
2. About the rotation: I don't know why the rotation happens the way it
   happens when you put `tick label style` inside a `tick label style`.
   But it's bad syntax, so just use the right syntax and put the
   `rotate` inside 1 `tick label style` instead of in 2.

Comment: This looks how I wanted it.

Comment: Please explain the syntax of `\def\discon{$\wr\!\!\!\wr$},`.

Comment: Why does `tick label style={rotate=-45}` within `xticklabel style=` rotate by 45 degrees the labels on the y-axis?  I have `tick label style={rotate=0}` within `yticklabel style=`.

Comment: @user74973 Check my edit.

Comment: Did you answer either of my questions?

Comment: @user74973 I tried to. What about it don't you understand?

Comment: The syntax.  What is `$\wr\!\!\!\wr$`?

Comment: `\wr` is a "vertical tilde". `\!`is negative (horizontal) space. The dollar signs make everything math mode. This needs to be mathmode because `\wr` only works in mathmode. So it is a vertical tilde followed by some negative space (so we are now slightly in front of that vertical tilde) followed by a second tilde.

Comment: Please reply to my question regarding `tick label style=`.  See the third `comment` after your code.

Comment: Did you see the edit that I made to my original post? This already (sort of) answers your second and third comment. If you need a (way) better explanation, then the comment section isn't the right place and you can start a new question.

Comment: I see your edits.  Sorry.  You already commented on `rotate`.

Comment: One more question on `wr`.  Why do you need this command for the break on the y-axis?  Here, shouldn't you use the `tilde`?  Your code "works," ... but I would ask "why does it 'work'?"

Comment: `\sim` (the tilde symbol) is not the same as a rotated `\wr`. The curvature differs a little bit. And as I wanted the two discontinuity symbols to be exactly the same, I rotated the `\wr` symbol when I used it on the y axis.

Comment: Yes, I want the two axis-break symbols to look exactly the same.  You have `extra y tick labels = {\discon},`.  From this code, I would expect the "vertical tildes" to be aligned vertically.

Comment: `extra y tick style` rotates them 90 degrees

Comment: In `extra x tick style  =`, you have `rotate=45,`.  Shouldn't that rotate the "vertical tildes" by 45 degrees?

Comment: Normally it would. But the 45 counteracts with the -45 in `xticklabel style`. -45 and 45 together rotate it 0 degrees.

Comment: Did you put the `rotate=-45,`  in `xticklabel style={rotate=-45},` only to "balance" the `rotate=45,` in `extra x tick style=`?

Comment: No, the rotate=-45 is something you put in there to rotate your x labels. So i used the rotate=45 to counteract your -45.

Answer (score 2):

The y axis doesn't need any discontinuity as it is near to zero already. Also discontinuity on both axes shows that origin is not relevant anyways.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}]
\begin{axis}[axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,width=10cm,height=5cm,
    grid=major, 
    title=Population of Pittsford in\\ 19\textsuperscript{th} Century,
    title style={align=center,font=\bfseries},
    ylabel = Population (in thousands),
    xlabel = Year,
    xmax=1900,xmin=1790,xtick={1800,1810,...,1900},
    ymin=0,ymax=2.5,
    axis x discontinuity=parallel,
]

\addplot+[draw=blue!50,mark size=1pt] plot coordinates{
(1800,1.1) (1810,1) (1820,0.9) (1830,1.2) 
(1840,1.5) (1850,1.5) (1860,1.5) (1870,1.7) 
(1880,1.75) (1890,1.75) (1900,1.9)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I originally had `title=\textbf{Population of Pittsford \\ in \boldmath$19^{\mathrm{th}}$ Century\unboldmath}` with the "\\".   I guess that `\textbf{}` obscured the "\\".  I see that I can get the title in bold with the command `title style={align=center,font=\bfseries},` and just have the title immediately following `title=`.

Comment: I do want the break on the y-axis. The scatter plot is artificially elevated in your plot. I edited the `axis` environment to include `xmin=1790,` and `xmax=1900,` and `xtick={1800,1810,...,1900},` and `ymin=0.6,` and `ymax=2,` and `ytick={0.8, 1, ..., 2},`. There are two mishaps with this, which I have not seen on any other scatter plot. First, the axis break symbol on the y-axis interferes with the axis break symbol on the x-axis. Can I make these parallel lines smaller? Second, the symbol for the breaks in the axes also occurs in my display on the top and right sides.

Comment: Also, I include the option `xticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white, tick label style={rotate=-45}},` so that all the years can be nicely fit along the x-axis. I don't want the numbers along the y-axis tilted. I have `yticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white, tick label style={rotate=0}},` after the xticklabel command, and the rotation-command is ignored.

Comment: @user74973 A discountinuity means that you are scaling the both axis and one side is too big to be shown completely. Here you don't have that problem hence it would be wrong if you put on the y axis because there is no gap.

Comment: In this case, having a break on the y-axis is unnecessary.  I am anticipating a scatter plot in which I will need breaks on both axes.

Comment: @Alenanno  May you help me with these typical modification to a scatter plot?